# Lyx: Presentation with beamer: How to use graphics/images/pictures

Tags: beamer, lyx, lyx-layouts

Pictures/images/graphics are for me a crucial part of presentations. Is anywhere a tutorial which describes how to use them in lyx with beamer layout? So with most important things to know how to use them: e.g. with columns and relative width information like that or using a pic as background for one slide or just behind on a fixed position.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXhMguG4J7U is a good tutorial but there is no information about images. And the official doc doesn't contain much information about that (beamer layout and images/graphics/...).

Is a tutorial for that available anywhere?